# Add footer all page document

Tags: java, pdf, itext, document

I am creating a pdf in Java. I want to add the same text to all the pages of the PDF. I could not do it because the number of pages is not constant. Could you help?

```
import com.lowagie.text.Document;

ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("MEPSAN PETROL CİHAZLARI SAN. TİC. A.Ş.", new Font(bf, 6, Font.BOLD)), 100, 30, 0);
```

The above code only adds to the current page.
How can I improve it?

Comment: What is the nature of this text? Is it a Header/Footer?

Comment: It is a footer.

Comment: How about something like `int pageCount = targetPdf.getPages().count()` and `public void addFooter(String footerText, int page){...}` and calling that method with `addFooter("MEPSAN...", pageCount-1) //-1 if based 0, remove if based 1`.

Comment: **IMPORTANT FOR WHOEVER HAS THE SAME QUESTION:** do **not** use the `HeaderFooter` class. It has been removed from iText almost a decade ago. I'd even say more: do **not** use any iText version that has my name in the package names (I am Lowagie; I am referring to `com.lowagie` packages). Those versions are at least 8 years old and [should not be used in a commercial context](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of HeaderFooter class in com.lowagie.text package.

Here is a working code example for reference:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter

Here is the documentation for the HeaderFooter class:

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/lowagie/text/HeaderFooter.html

Comment or inbox you need further assistance/clarification.

Comment: **IMPORTANT FOR WHOEVER HAS THE SAME QUESTION:** do **not** use the `HeaderFooter` class. It has been removed from iText almost a decade ago. I'd even say more: do **not** use any iText version that has my name in the package names (I am Lowagie; I am referring to `com.lowagie` packages). Those versions are at least 8 years old and [should not be used in a commercial context](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I agree, sir. The answer is just for this problem's sake as the person is already using lowagie packages. :)

Comment: I know, the comment wasn't criticizing your answer. I'll even up-vote it. I just wanted to clarify.